# Can't resolve module 'child_process'

Tags: node.js, electron, shelljs

I have an angular2 webpack project that is running in electron. I'm trying to use `shelljs` but webpack fails to build with the error:

```
[0] ERROR in ./~/shelljs/src/exec.js
[0] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in 'D:\Projects\angular-electron\node_modules\shelljs\src'
[0]  @ ./~/shelljs/src/exec.js 6:12-36
[0]  @ ./~/shelljs/src ^\.\/.*$
[0]  @ ./~/shelljs/shell.js
```

My webpack configuration is targeting the `electron-renderer` and my polyfills are using `zone-node`:

```
return { 
    target: 'electron-renderer', //webpack-build-common.js
    ...
```

and

```
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node'; //polyfills.ts
```

I have tried changing the webpack target to `node` but it has no effect.

You can see my entire webpack configuration on [paste bin](https://pastebin.com/JREHZX9w)

Comment: A bit late for you, but this seems to be similar - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44305603/types-node-installed-typescript-version-not-able-find-module-child-process

Comment: I wonder if editing `package.json` is the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54459622/470749

Answer (score 0):

Choose call exec into main.ts electron in ipcrender, work fine
example:

```html
ipcMain.on('ipc-callchild', async (event, arg) => {
  const child = require('child_process').execFile;
  const executablePath = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\browser.exe ";
  let parameters = [`${arg}`, "--kiosk", "--private-window"];
  child(executablePath, parameters, function(err, data) {
  console.log(err)
  console.log(data.toString());
  });
});
```