# @types/node installed typescript version not able find module" child_process"

Tags: node.js, angular

I found typescript version for [node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/node) unfortunately it's not able find **"child_process"** module from the node packages.

Exactly the error message in my console is **Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process'**

When I went through some blog they recommended to add below code in your **tsconfig.json** file.

```
"typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ]
```

Same thing as I pasted over here unlikely it's did't help.

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2016",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

Why they don't inject this node module ? Am I doing something wrong in tsconfig.json file?  I would be a grateful if you could give a little help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12):

Maybe is the path:

```
"typeRoots": [
      "../node_modules/@types"
    ]
```

Usually you have your **tsconfig** in a `src`.

**Update:**

My original answer makes no sense, because you have this `"baseUrl": "src"`.

As instead, I believe it could be a Webpack issue.

Try adding this to your **webpack.config** file:

```
target: 'node'
```

**Update 2:**

Workaround: Add the following to your config file:

```
node: {
      child_process: 'empty'
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work . Any other way that I can debug to ensure a path ?

Comment: @QuokMoon Check my update, I think it may be a webpack issue.

Comment: I should change in webpack.config or tsconfig.js file?

Comment: @QuokMoon In your `webpack.config.js`

Comment: On which file is Update 2 supposed to go to?
I'm getting an error when I paste in tsconfig.json

Comment: @SrAxi Where is the webpack.config file located? To the best of my knowledge, I can't find it anywhere. Thanks!

Comment: Adding `node: { child_process: 'empty' }` as a top-level option in `webpack.config.js` fixed the problem I was having.

Comment: im using js how does it work for js?