# Module not found: Error can't resolve 'child_process', how to fix?

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, jupyter-lab

I'm trying to create a JupyterLab extension, it uses typescript.

I've successfully added the package "@types/node" allowing me to use packages such as 'require('http')'.

But as soon as I try to use child process, using 'require("child_process")' I get the following error when trying to build the extension.

```
ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in '/home/fionn/anaconda3/envs/jupyterlab-ext/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/jupyerlab_xkdc/lib'
    at factory.create (/home/fionn/anaconda3/envs/jupyterlab-ext/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:535:10)
    at factory (/home/fionn/anaconda3/envs/jupyterlab-ext/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:397:22)
    at resolver (/home/fionn/anaconda3/envs/jupyterlab-ext/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:130:21)
    at asyncLib.parallel (/home/fionn/anaconda3/envs/jupyterlab-ext/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:224:22)
    at /home/fionn/anaconda3/envs/jupyterlab-ext/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/neo-async/async.js:2825:7
    at /home/fionn/anaconda3/envs/jupyterlab-ext/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/neo-async/async.js:6886:13
    at normalResolver.resolve (/home/fionn/anaconda3/envs/jupyterlab-ext/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:214:25)
    at doResolve (/home/fionn/anaconda3/envs/jupyterlab-ext/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:184:12)
    at hook.callAsync (/home/fionn/anaconda3/envs/jupyterlab-ext/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:238:5)
    at _fn0 (eval at create (/home/fionn/anaconda3/envs/jupyterlab-ext/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:32:10), <anonymous>:15:1)
    at resolver.doResolve (/home/fionn/anaconda3/envs/jupyterlab-ext/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/UnsafeCachePlugin.js:37:5)
    at hook.callAsync (/home/fionn/anaconda3/envs/jupyterlab-ext/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:238:5)
    at _fn0 (eval at create (/home/fionn/anaconda3/envs/jupyterlab-ext/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:32:10), <anonymous>:15:1)
    at hook.callAsync (/home/fionn/anaconda3/envs/jupyterlab-ext/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:238:5)
    at _fn0 (eval at create (/home/fionn/anaconda3/envs/jupyterlab-ext/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:32:10), <anonymous>:12:1)
    at resolver.doResolve (/home/fionn/anaconda3/envs/jupyterlab-ext/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/DescriptionFilePlugin.js:42:38)
    at hook.callAsync (/home/fionn/anaconda3/envs/jupyterlab-ext/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:238:5)
    at _fn41 (eval at create (/home/fionn/anaconda3/envs/jupyterlab-ext/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:32:10), <anonymous>:381:1)
    at resolver.doResolve (/home/fionn/anaconda3/envs/jupyterlab-ext/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/ModuleKindPlugin.js:23:37)
    at hook.callAsync (/home/fionn/anaconda3/envs/jupyterlab-ext/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:238:5)
    at _fn0 (eval at create (/home/fionn/anaconda3/envs/jupyterlab-ext/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:32:10), <anonymous>:15:1)
    at hook.callAsync (/home/fionn/anaconda3/envs/jupyterlab-ext/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:238:5)
    at _fn0 (eval at create (/home/fionn/anaconda3/envs/jupyterlab-ext/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:32:10), <anonymous>:15:1)
    at args (/home/fionn/anaconda3/envs/jupyterlab-ext/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/forEachBail.js:30:14)
    at hook.callAsync (/home/fionn/anaconda3/envs/jupyterlab-ext/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:238:5)
    at _fn0 (eval at create (/home/fionn/anaconda3/envs/jupyterlab-ext/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:32:10), <anonymous>:15:1)
    at resolver.doResolve (/home/fionn/anaconda3/envs/jupyterlab-ext/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/UnsafeCachePlugin.js:37:5)
    at hook.callAsync (/home/fionn/anaconda3/envs/jupyterlab-ext/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:238:5)
    at _fn0 (eval at create (/home/fionn/anaconda3/envs/jupyterlab-ext/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:32:10), <anonymous>:15:1)
    at hook.callAsync (/home/fionn/anaconda3/envs/jupyterlab-ext/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:238:5) resolve 'child_process' in '/home/fionn/anaconda3/envs/jupyterlab-ext/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/jupyerlab_xkdc/lib' Parsed request is a module   using description file: /home/fionn/anaconda3/envs/jupyterlab-ext/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/jupyerlab_xkdc/package.json (relative path: ./lib)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
    resolve as module
      /home/fionn/anaconda3/envs/jupyterlab-ext/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/jupyerlab_xkdc/lib/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /home/fionn/anaconda3/envs/jupyterlab-ext/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /home/fionn/anaconda3/envs/jupyterlab-ext/share/jupyter/lab/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /home/fionn/anaconda3/envs/jupyterlab-ext/share/jupyter/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /home/fionn/anaconda3/envs/jupyterlab-ext/share/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /home/fionn/anaconda3/envs/jupyterlab-ext/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /home/fionn/anaconda3/envs/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /home/fionn/anaconda3/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /home/fionn/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /home/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      looking for modules in /home/fionn/anaconda3/envs/jupyterlab-ext/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/jupyerlab_xkdc/node_modules
        using description file: /home/fionn/anaconda3/envs/jupyterlab-ext/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/jupyerlab_xkdc/package.json (relative path: ./node_modules)
          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
      looking for modules in /home/fionn/anaconda3/envs/jupyterlab-ext/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules
        using description file: /home/fionn/anaconda3/envs/jupyterlab-ext/share/jupyter/lab/staging/package.json (relative path: ./node_modules)
          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
          using description file: /home/fionn/anaconda3/envs/jupyterlab-ext/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/child_process/package.json (relative path: .)
            no extension
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
          using description file: /home/fionn/anaconda3/envs/jupyterlab-ext/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/jupyerlab_xkdc/package.json (relative path: ./node_modules/child_process)
            no extension
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /home/fionn/anaconda3/envs/jupyterlab-ext/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/child_process is not a file
            .wasm
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /home/fionn/anaconda3/envs/jupyterlab-ext/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/jupyerlab_xkdc/node_modules/child_process doesn't exist
            .wasm
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /home/fionn/anaconda3/envs/jupyterlab-ext/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/child_process.wasm doesn't exist
            .mjs
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /home/fionn/anaconda3/envs/jupyterlab-ext/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/jupyerlab_xkdc/node_modules/child_process.wasm doesn't exist
            .mjs
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /home/fionn/anaconda3/envs/jupyterlab-ext/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/child_process.mjs doesn't exist
            .js
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /home/fionn/anaconda3/envs/jupyterlab-ext/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/jupyerlab_xkdc/node_modules/child_process.mjs doesn't exist
            .js
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /home/fionn/anaconda3/envs/jupyterlab-ext/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/child_process.js doesn't exist
            .json
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /home/fionn/anaconda3/envs/jupyterlab-ext/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/jupyerlab_xkdc/node_modules/child_process.js doesn't exist
            .json
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /home/fionn/anaconda3/envs/jupyterlab-ext/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/child_process.json doesn't exist
              /home/fionn/anaconda3/envs/jupyterlab-ext/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/jupyerlab_xkdc/node_modules/child_process.json doesn't exist
            as directory
              existing directory
                use ./index.js from main in package.json
                  using description file: /home/fionn/anaconda3/envs/jupyterlab-ext/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/child_process/package.json (relative path: .)
                    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
            as directory
              /home/fionn/anaconda3/envs/jupyterlab-ext/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/jupyerlab_xkdc/node_modules/child_process doesn't exist
                    using description file: /home/fionn/anaconda3/envs/jupyterlab-ext/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/child_process/package.json (relative path: ./index.js)
                      no extension
                        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                        /home/fionn/anaconda3/envs/jupyterlab-ext/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/child_process/index.js doesn't exist
                      .wasm
                        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                        /home/fionn/anaconda3/envs/jupyterlab-ext/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/child_process/index.js.wasm doesn't exist
                      .mjs
                        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                        /home/fionn/anaconda3/envs/jupyterlab-ext/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/child_process/index.js.mjs doesn't exist
                      .js
                        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                        /home/fionn/anaconda3/envs/jupyterlab-ext/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/child_process/index.js.js doesn't exist
                      .json
                        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                        /home/fionn/anaconda3/envs/jupyterlab-ext/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/child_process/index.js.json doesn't exist
                      as directory
                        /home/fionn/anaconda3/envs/jupyterlab-ext/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/child_process/index.js doesn't exist
                using path: /home/fionn/anaconda3/envs/jupyterlab-ext/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/child_process/index
                  using description file: /home/fionn/anaconda3/envs/jupyterlab-ext/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/child_process/package.json (relative path: ./index)
                    no extension
                      Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                      /home/fionn/anaconda3/envs/jupyterlab-ext/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/child_process/index doesn't exist
                    .wasm
                      Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                      /home/fionn/anaconda3/envs/jupyterlab-ext/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/child_process/index.wasm doesn't exist
                    .mjs
                      Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                      /home/fionn/anaconda3/envs/jupyterlab-ext/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/child_process/index.mjs doesn't exist
                    .js
                      Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                      /home/fionn/anaconda3/envs/jupyterlab-ext/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/child_process/index.js doesn't exist
                    .json
                      Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
                      /home/fionn/anaconda3/envs/jupyterlab-ext/share/jupyter/lab/staging/node_modules/child_process/index.json doesn't exist error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

I've googled around but still have no idea what to do to resolve this issue.

Any pointers or info at all would be greatly appreciated.

My packages.json file.

```
{
  "name": "jupyerlab_xkdc",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "Short description",
  "keywords": [
    "jupyter",
    "jupyterlab",
    "jupyterlab-extension"
  ],
  "homepage": "https://github.com/my_name/myextension",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/my_name/myextension/issues"
  },
  "license": "BSD-3-Clause",
  "author": "Fionn McKnight",
  "files": [
    "lib/**/*.{d.ts,eot,gif,html,jpg,js,js.map,json,png,svg,woff2,ttf}",
    "style/**/*.{css,eot,gif,html,jpg,json,png,svg,woff2,ttf}"
  ],
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "types": "lib/index.d.ts",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/my_name/myextension.git"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",
    "clean": "rimraf lib",
    "prepare": "npm run clean && npm run build",
    "watch": "tsc -w"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@jupyterlab/application": "^0.19.1",
    "@jupyterlab/apputils": "^0.19.1",
    "@phosphor/coreutils": "^1.3.0",
    "@phosphor/messaging": "^1.2.2",
    "@phosphor/widgets": "^1.6.0",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.29",
    "@types/node": "^10.12.19",
    "child_process": "^1.0.2",
    "npm": "^6.7.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^10.12.19",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.1",
    "typescript": "~3.1.1"
  },
  "jupyterlab": {
    "extension": true
  }
}
```

Comment: Is this even the full stack error?

Comment: Can you show us your package.json?

Comment: yes, when I go to the folder 'child_process' it's empty besides a readme stating that "this package is not currently in use, but was formerly occupied by another package".

Comment: Added my packages.json

Comment: I wonder if https://stackoverflow.com/a/59381357/470749 is related.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

**just put in package.json**

```
"browser":{
"child_process": false
}
```

are you using webpack

Comment: I added that and no longer got the error, thanks.

Sorry I'm very new to all of this, I'm not sure if I'm using webpack, how can I tell? 

Also, can you explain why I needed to add this to my package.json? 

Thanks!

Comment: adding **browser: {  child_process: false }** to the package.json means: to tell webpack that it's ok for the module to get an empty object for this modules.weback implicitly used by the node_modules..and you can also use it explicity tooo.if you use explicitly than you have to define it configration in webpack.config.js file

Comment: Ok but I don't want it to be an empty object, I have 'const spawn = require("child_process").spawn', which is now returning undefined.

Comment: use node.js internal child process module .that could help or try sync version of spawn this could help [ https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html ]

Comment: same issue [ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44305603/types-node-installed-typescript-version-not-able-find-module-child-process ]

Comment: Make sure that you're not importing anything more than you really want to :)))

Answer (score 16):

In newer versions I used:

```
// webpack.config.js
...,
resolve: {
    extensions: [".ts", ".js"],
    fallback: {
      "child_process": false,
      // and also other packages that are not found
    }
  },
```

Comment: what is the exact version when you say new?

Comment: @SaurabhGupta I said newer, not new. Might be outdated by now. I don't remember the version, which I was using at the time.

Answer (score 13):

I got a similar error while trying to run **`storybook.js`** which uses **webpack**.

#### For Webpack

You can add the following to the webpack's config to fix the build -

```js
// webpack.config.js
...,
node: {
    child_process: "empty"
    // fs: "empty", // if unable to resolve "fs"
},
```

You can also set other conflicting modules to `"empty"` if they are responsible for breaking the build.

[Reference for Webpack's config.node](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/node/)

Answer (score 5):

I stayed blocked for a couple of times on that.
As far I understood, it seems impossible to execute some child_process ( which is literally executing some cmd ) from the browser, which also makes sense at some point.
The solution given works for me, adding below to `package.json` is working

```
  "browser": { "fs": false, "child_process": false }
```

**But** don't add it on your package.json (mean the one of your app), but instead the `package.json` from the lib then you are using where the
`require('child_process')` is.

That's being done, this fixe just said to the compiler that's it's ok to not have a lib even if this one is required somewhere on your code or dependencies (rather to crash ). If you want to use child_process from your App I am afraid that it's complicated.

Here is the [source](https://github.com/wagenaartje/neataptic/issues/57#issuecomment-387303055) of my post

Answer (score 3):

Randomly Got this issue while using next.js
I got it resolved by clearing out,

```
.next
node_modules
```

folders
Guess it may work for people getting this client process error in next js

Comment: got the same issue... how did you clear them? recreate the application ?

Comment: I just cleared the folders mentioned in my answer. When i did npm i and npm run, it worked without any issues.

Comment: thanks for you feedback. My problem was incorrect import of firebase. i copy/pasted the import statement from somewhere else and this caused that same error. maybe it helps someone. :)

Answer (score 3):

For me, by mistake `import` was added to file that created issue.

```
import { debug } from "webpack";
```

Answer (score 3):

I got this in **next.js** after importing `path` and `fs` in a page.

Solved it by placing them in the `getStaticProps()` function.