# How to set up a NativeScript Vue code sharing project in a Nuxt project

Tags: vue.js, webpack, nativescript, nuxt.js, nativescript-vue

I tried to set up a codesharing NativeScript project in an existing Nuxt.js project using the nativescript-vue-cli-plugin. Unfortunately the plugin leaves me with several errors after setup.

1. Nativescript Vue seems to parse all component files as nativescript templates (and fails of course). I could append the "web" attribute to every `<template>` in my project but nuxt does not parse them anymore when I do this. How can I achieve that Nuxt uses `<template web>` templates?
2. Webpack can't resolve some modules. For example I'd like to import a css file located in `@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.css`. Webpack seems to read this as `./@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.css` and can't resolve it. How do I have to modify the webpack config that this works?
3. A Module I use for the web version, compile-sass, throws an error because it can't resolve "child_process". The error does not appear when I use it with nuxt. I found a [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459442/module-not-found-error-cant-resolve-child-process-how-to-fix) which addresses this issue in an other context but the solution does not work for me.
4. Unless I run `tns preview` etc. directly instead of `npm run preview:ios` etc., Nativescript does not find the main.native.json file defined in nsconfig.js in the project root. That means it has to do something with the `npm run setup-webpack-config` command.

Some of these problems are very specific to my setup so a more general guide about how to use Nativescript codesharing with a Nuxt project would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you taken a look to the code sharing section of the documentation: https://nativescript-vue.org/en/docs/getting-started/code-sharing/

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Yes, I followed the steps there to set it up, however the documentation does not have any advices for troubleshooting. I managed to install the cli plugin which added dependencies and package scripts as intended. It also added an ns_example folder. I copied App_Resources and main.native.js (adapted) into my nuxt project folder. Then I added an nsconfig.json as described [in the nativescript documentation](https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/project-structure-app#the-nsconfigjson-file) to change the app path where main.native.js is located.

Comment: I found out how to exclude files with .native.vue as ending over .nuxtignore (https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-ignore/). I still don‘t have a solution for all the other difficulties