# Find video codec in react

Tags: reactjs

I'm looking for a way to determine the video codec of videos the user uploads on the react frontend(app written in ts); so far this is what I tried doing:

```
  var probe = require('ffprobe');

  for (let i1 = 0; i1 < files.length; i1++) {    
    if (files[i1].type.split("/")[0] === "video"){
      probe(files[i1], function(err: Error, probeData: any)
      {
        if(probeData.streams[0].codec_name === 'h265'){
          videosToTranscode.push(files[i1]);
        }
      });
    }
  }
  if(videosToTranscode === undefined || videosToTranscode.length == 0){
    transcodeVideos(videosToTranscode);
  }
```

The problem is that I'm greeted with the following message : "./node_modules/node-ffprobe/lib/ffprobe.js:1:0 Module not found: Can't resolve 'child_process'"

My understanding is child_process is integrated in the browser; so I'm guessing I'm doing something wrong with the require statement ? If I create a project, without react, in the same vein with fluent-ffmpeg and probe a video url herewith I don't have that problem.

Any clues ?

Comment: There is this other SO post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54459622/11149106

Comment: Thanks for the reply Monstar; I had tried that, in some form but still no luck: I get the exact same compile error.