# module not found: cant resolve 'child_process' in '/home/fawad/pmc-frontend_master/node_modules/dialog'

Tags: npm, npm-install

I run npm run build than show this error plz tell me the solution

module not found: cant resolve 'child_process' in '/home/fawad/pmc-frontend_master/node_modules/dialog'

I try this npm install child_process and also npm install child_process --legacy-peer-deps but not work this

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Module not found: Error can't resolve 'child\_process', how to fix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459442/module-not-found-error-cant-resolve-child-process-how-to-fix)

Answer (score 0):

Try put in `package.json` this:

```
"browser":{
"child_process": false
}
```

For more look at this [Module not found: Error can't resolve 'child_process', how to fix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459442/module-not-found-error-cant-resolve-child-process-how-to-fix)

Comment: bro I try this "browser":{
"child_process": false
}  but not solve error plz  tell me another way to solve this error

Comment: can u edit post and attach full error code? Maybe can explain better and help us to find a solution

Comment: Module not found: Error: Can't 'child_process' in '/home/fawad/pmc-frontend-master@6cd9d075e58/node_module/dialog'      Bro this error show when i run command npm run  build