# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in node_module

Tags: npm-install, child-process, npm-package

During npm run build i face this error i try to install child process but not solve error

this error will occcur

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in '/home/fawad/pmc-frontend-master@6cd9d075e58/node_modules/dialog'

Answer (score 0):

Refer this site..

[Module not found: Error can't resolve 'child_process', how to fix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459442/module-not-found-error-cant-resolve-child-process-how-to-fix)

add below lines in package.json

```
"browser":{
"child_process": false
}
```

Comment: brother     "browser":{
"child_process": false
}    i try this but not solve error