# Unhandled Runtime Error TypeError: fs.existsSync is not a function. Unable to use lqip-modern

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, next.js

I am using Next 13.4.5
My problems started when i imported lqip-modern (i am new to that)

```
./node_modules/sharp/build/Release/sharp-win32-x64.node
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:2)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
(Source code omitted for this binary file)
```

I solve it by adding the following lines of code to the next.config.js file:

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */

const path = require('path')
const nextConfig = {
    sassOptions: {
        includePaths: [path.join(__dirname, 'styles')],
      },
      //from here
      webpack: (config) => {
        config.module.rules.push({
          test: /\.node$/,
          loader: 'node/loader',
            
        })
     
        return config
      },
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

the next prolem that apear is:

```
./node_modules/detect-libc/lib/detect-libc.js:6:0
Module not found: Can't resolve 'child_process'

https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found

Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/sharp/lib/utility.js
./node_modules/sharp/lib/index.js
./node_modules/lqip-modern/index.js
./src/app/components/(main)/main.jsx
./src/app/layout.js
```

to solve it I follow thw idea of that post: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459442/module-not-found-error-cant-resolve-child-process-how-to-fix#:~:text=I%20stayed%20blocked,of%20my%20post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459442/module-not-found-error-cant-resolve-child-process-how-to-fix#:%7E:text=I%20stayed%20blocked,of%20my%20post)
In that case by adding

```
//detect-libc/package.json

  "browser":{
    "child_process": false
    }
```

the i complete it with "fs": false

```
//detect-libc/package.json

  "browser":{
    "child_process": false,
    "fs": false
    } ,
```

due to that error:

```
./node_modules/detect-libc/lib/filesystem.js (6:0)
Module not found: Can't resolve 'fs'

https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found

Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/detect-libc/lib/detect-libc.js
./node_modules/sharp/lib/utility.js
./node_modules/sharp/lib/index.js
./node_modules/lqip-modern/index.js
./src/app/components/(main)/main.jsx
./src/app/layout.js
```

Then
`Module not found: Can't resolve 'child_process'` 
and
`Module not found: Can't resolve 'fs'`
errors apear, but related to the sharp library, so i solve them in the order they apear:
Error:

```
./node_modules/sharp/lib/libvips.js:3:0
Module not found: Can't resolve 'fs'

https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found

Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/sharp/lib/constructor.js
./node_modules/sharp/lib/index.js
./node_modules/lqip-modern/index.js
./src/app/components/(main)/main.jsx
./src/app/layout.js
```

Solution:

```
//sharp/package.json
"browser":{
    "fs": false
    }
```

Error:

```
Module not found: Can't resolve 'child_process'

https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found

Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/sharp/lib/constructor.js
./node_modules/sharp/lib/index.js
./node_modules/lqip-modern/index.js
./src/app/components/(main)/main.jsx
./src/app/layout.js
```

Solution:

```
//sharp/package.json
"browser":{
    "fs": false,
    "child_process": false
    }
```

but then the following error appear:

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
TypeError: fs.existsSync is not a function

Call Stack
Object.hasVendoredLibvips
node_modules\sharp\lib\libvips.js (83:0)
eval
node_modules\sharp\lib\constructor.js (7:39)
(app-client)/./node_modules/sharp/lib/constructor.js
file:///C:/Users/Pablo/Documents/Programas/paginaWebPaco/next13/next13/.next/static/chunks/app/layout.js (1110:1)
options.factory
/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js (716:31)
__webpack_require__
file:///C:/Users/Pablo/Documents/Programas/paginaWebPaco/next13/next13/.next/static/chunks/webpack.js (37:33)
fn
/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js (371:21)
eval
node_modules\sharp\lib\index.js (3:14)
(app-client)/./node_modules/sharp/lib/index.js
file:///C:/Users/Pablo/Documents/Programas/paginaWebPaco/next13/next13/.next/static/chunks/app/layout.js (1121:1)
options.factory
/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js (716:31)
__webpack_require__
file:///C:/Users/Pablo/Documents/Programas/paginaWebPaco/next13/next13/.next/static/chunks/webpack.js (37:33)
fn
/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js (371:21)
eval
node_modules\lqip-modern\index.js (3:14)
(app-client)/./node_modules/lqip-modern/index.js
file:///C:/Users/Pablo/Documents/Programas/paginaWebPaco/next13/next13/.next/static/chunks/app/layout.js (331:1)
options.factory
/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js (716:31)
__webpack_require__
file:///C:/Users/Pablo/Documents/Programas/paginaWebPaco/next13/next13/.next/static/chunks/webpack.js (37:33)
fn
/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js (371:21)
eval
webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./src/app/components/(main)/main.jsx (12:69)
(app-client)/./src/app/components/(main)/main.jsx
file:///C:/Users/Pablo/Documents/Programas/paginaWebPaco/next13/next13/.next/static/chunks/app/layout.js (801:1)
options.factory
/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js (716:31)
__webpack_require__
file:///C:/Users/Pablo/Documents/Programas/paginaWebPaco/next13/next13/.next/static/chunks/webpack.js (37:33)
fn
/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js (371:21)
eval
webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./src/app/layout.js (9:79)
(app-client)/./src/app/layout.js
file:///C:/Users/Pablo/Documents/Programas/paginaWebPaco/next13/next13/.next/static/chunks/app/layout.js (823:1)
options.factory
/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js (716:31)
__webpack_require__
file:///C:/Users/Pablo/Documents/Programas/paginaWebPaco/next13/next13/.next/static/chunks/webpack.js (37:33)
fn
/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js (371:21)
Next.js
requireModule
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-server-dom-webpack\cjs\react-server-dom-webpack-client.browser.development.js (144:0)
initializeModuleChunk
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-server-dom-webpack\cjs\react-server-dom-webpack-client.browser.development.js (1205:0)
resolveModuleChunk
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-server-dom-webpack\cjs\react-server-dom-webpack-client.browser.development.js (1163:0)
eval
node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-server-dom-webpack\cjs\react-server-dom-webpack-client.browser.development.js (1590:0)
```

**Note: when i stop importing the lqip image the problem disapear, but I dont even started to use it**

The file where i imported the library:

```
import Image, {ImageProps} from 'next/image';

import cloudinaryLoader from '../../api/cloudinaryLoader';
// import normalizeSrc from '../../api/cloudinaryLoader.js';
import style from './main.module.scss';
import lqipModern from "lqip-modern";
import { GetStaticProps } from 'next';




export default function Main({ children, headerHeight }) {
    console.log(headerHeight);
    return (
        <>
            <div className={style.positionfix}>
                <div className={style.imageContainer}>
                    <Image
                        loader={cloudinaryLoader}
                        src='v1687550138/s2edited.webp'
                        alt={'df'}
                        sizes='100vw'
                        fill
                        style={{ objectFit: 'cover' }}
                        // placeholder='blur'
                    />
                </div>
            </div>
            <main
                className={style.main}
                
            >
                {children}
            </main>
        </>
    );
}
```

The package.json of my project:

```
{
    "name": "next13",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "next dev",
        "build": "next build",
        "start": "next start",
        "lint": "next lint",
        "format": "prettier --writte ."
    },
    "dependencies": {
    
        "classnames": "^2.3.2",
        "eslint": "8.42.0",
        "eslint-config-next": "13.4.5",
        "lqip-modern": "^2.0.0",
        "next": "13.4.5",
        "raw-loader": "^4.0.2",
        "react": "18.2.0",
        "react-dom": "18.2.0"
    },
    "devDependencies": {

        "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.8.0",
        "node-loader": "^2.0.0",
        "prettier": "^2.8.8",
        "sass": "^1.63.3",
        "typescript": "^5.1.6"
    }
}
```

**I also tried to add**

```
"browser":{
    "child_process": false,
    "fs": false
    }
```

**to the package.json of my project and the result is the same**

If you need any additional information just tell me, Thank you in advance if you've made it this far.I appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: This library is a node library. Consider not using it in browser code.